# Exec native application using Java within docker (native app requires additional native library)

Tags: java, docker, exec, executable

I dive into this riddle: I'm using native application to grab data and grabbed data are processed within Java application (microservice). The native application is golang application and requires 'libgo.so' library. So far so good. But now I need to run the service from docker - and here comes the problem. What are the minimal steps to correctly incorporate native library to docker image with all necessary native libraries? The Java application is build using 'jib-maven-plugin'.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Pat

Comment: Install go in the image?

Comment: The newer version of the native application is build statically, so it solved the issue.